# How to modify the query that the views integration with the chart API module provides?

Tags: views, charts

I am using Google Charts API module to generate a pie chart of a content type with the fields **Blood-group** and **count** representing the sectors.

For this I need to completely alter the query (= select from a different table) that the views integration provides.

**My question**: Can I use `hook_views_query_alter`?

Comment: Yes you can. Post the code which you are trying..

Comment: Hmmm. Found it easier to write my own custom module. Greater flexibility. Charting with views on 7 hasn't been really good to me.

Comment: I havent tried with query_alter. In my chart_views module, I added the function chart_views_views_pre_execute() {
  if($view->name=="charts")
   {
       $view->build_info['query']="select field_blood_group_value,count(*) from field_data_field_blood_group group by field_blood_group_value";
   }
}                                                     However, this gave me an Ajax 500 error                                               Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To create charts in Drupal, there are plenty of modules available. Refer to the [comparison of charting modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985) for an overview. After doing so, it should be clear that the names (and namespaces) of various charting modules are pretty confusing. Therefor I suggest you add a link to the exact 'Google Charts API' module this question is about.

Moreover, if I correctly understand the question, it seems to me that this is a rather straight forward requirement that can be easily addressed with (at least) the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module, i.e. the views integration of it (provides a new views style plugin to transform tabular view results into a chart). I recently created quite a lot of new [Charts documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/233753) that should help to get started with it.

The [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module ships with [out-of-the-box](https://www.drupal.org/node/2426921) samples which are straight forward to adapt to fit your needs, e.g. by cloning these samples in a new views display or a new view. Of course there are other alternatives in that comparison that might be a better fit for this specific case.

Be aware: I'm a new (co-) maintainer of both [Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart) and [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) (confusing module names, I didn't invent them), and the author of the [comparison of charting modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985).